# Storing value of image id in a variable - jQuery

Tags: jquery, variables, image

I want to store the value of id of an image when I click it, in a variable. How do I do that?

Comment: could you show us some of your markup for us to better help you specifically regarding selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one image:

```
var id;
$('img').click(function() {
  id = this.id;
});
```

For multiple images:

```
var ids = [];
$('img').click(function() {
  ids.push(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$('img').click(function(){
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help to have more information about what you're trying to do, however to answer your question directly:

```
$("img").click(function(){
var imageId = $(this).attr("id");
}
);
```